# Defining enums in Cython code that will be used in the C part of code

Tags: python, enums, cython, cpython

I have defined and `enum` in cython header file `api.pxd`:

```
ctypedef enum InstructionType:
    default = 0
    end_if = 1
    end_loop = 2
    backward_jump_here = 4
```

I also have checked if turning `ctypedef` to `cdef` would work (and it didn't).

And I want to use value from this enum in `__cinit__` method fo some class:

```
from api cimport Instruction, CLinVM, InstructionType

# (...) some other classes

cdef class EndIf(Noop):
   def __cinit__(self):
      self.type = InstructionType.end_if
```

And I get compilation error:

```
    self.type = InstructionType.end_if
                              ^
------------------------------------------------------------
 /home/(...)/instructions.pyx:149:35: 'InstructionType' is not a constant,
```

Any way to define and use enum in such way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not access enumerated constants through their typename they belong to, neither in C, nor in C++, nor in Cython. You'd need to create a *wrapper .pxd* for it.

Comment: I can access this constants using their names 'end_if' and so on. Thanks for the hint!