# How to access an enum type by value in cython

Tags: python, enums, cython

I was handed some code that looks like this:

In "header.hpp":

```
enum class my_enum_type {
    val1 = 0;
    ... 
}
```

In "header_lib.pyx":

```
cdef extern from "header.hpp":
    enum my_enum_type:
        val1 = 0;
        ...
...
```

Later in "header_lib.pyx":

```
def foo():
    ...
    return my_enum_type.val1
```

I was told this should have no problems, but that is not the case from my experience just now,and as evident in this post: [Defining enums in Cython code that will be used in the C part of code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9341511/defining-enums-in-cython-code-that-will-be-used-in-the-c-part-of-code).

However, it doesn't recognize "val1" by itself either if I write "return val1". What's the correct way to do this?

Comment: Did you check the answer below?

Comment: Try [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66037988/208880) for reading cpp files and creating `Enum`s.

Answer (score 10):

You can declare a `enum` in Cython as:

```
ctypedef enum options: OPT1, OPT2, OPT3
```

or

```
ctypedef enum options:
    OPT1,
    OPT2,
    OPT3
```

And and example could be:

```
def main():
    cdef options test
    test = OPT2
    f(test)

cdef void f(options inp):
    if inp == OPT1:
        print('OPT1')
    elif inp == OPT2:
        print('OPT2')
    elif inp == OPT3:
        print('OPT3')
```

When running `main()` you will see `"OPT2"` printed. You could pass the variable `test` to a `C` or `C++` function in the same way as shown here for the `cdef` function.

Comment: Note that the OP asks about `enum class` not `enum`.

Comment: The problem I see with this technique is that you cannot convert from a string to the original enum class, and in the pure Python world there is no notion of `enum`, thus Python cannot easily check the object type, the enum name or the underlying value.

Comment: @ibarrond I haven't checked it, but I think Python recognizes the enum options as integer values. Good point though...

Comment: That's right, Cython enums are just ints at Python level.

Answer (score 5):

To maintain the duality of Cython/C/C++ enum class and Python Enum class functionalities, I propose a solution with mirroring classes. This solution is divided in two components:

1. On one side we have a Cython/C/C++ enum. This enum can either be originated by wrapping C/C++ code in an extern block...

   ```
    cdef extern from "header.h":
        enum my_c_enum_type:
            OPT1 = 0,
            OPT2,
            OPT3,
   ```

   ... or directly in Cython.

   ```
    ctypedef enum my_cy_enum_type:
        OPT1=0,    #Default value is 0
        OPT2,      #Default value is 1
        OPT3,      #Default value is 2
   ```
2. On the other we have Python. Since Python 3.4, there is a supported class Enum that emulates that functionality ([link to official documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html)). **Here we should replicate the enum elements in pure Python**. You can make use of the `auto` function to fill the Enum just like in C/C++/Cython:

   ```
    from enum import Enum, auto
    class my_py_enum_type(Enum):
        OPT1=0
        OPT2=auto()
        OPT3=auto()
   ```

Now, in order to use this dual Python & Cython solution:

```py
    # PYTHON: we use the my_py_enum_type Enum
    enum_obj = my_py_enum_type(1)        # Corresponds to OPT2
    print(enum_obj.value, enum_obj.name) # We can access the value and the name 
    #> 1, OPT2
    s='OPT2'; enum_obj = getattr(my_py_enum_type, s) # We can create them from the string 'OPT2'


    # PYTHON TO CYTHON
    def func(enum_obj):
        if not isinstance(enum_obj, my_py_enum_type):
             raise TypeError
        # Use in a cython function that accepts only my_c_enum_type Cython enum
        myCythonEnumFunc(enum_obj.value) # Convert to C/Cython enum using value
        ...

    # CYTHON TO PYTHON
    def func():
        # a Cython enum
        cdef my_c_enum_type cy_enum_obj = val1
        # creating a python enum
        return my_p_enum_type(cy_enum_obj)  # Convert using the full cy_enum
        ...
```

This solution translates Cython/C enums (which in Python are mere ints) into a proper Python Enum class with the same characteristics, and translates the value inside a Python Enum object into the original Cython class. You get the best of both worlds!

Answer (score 2):

You can use cpdef to directly create a Python Enum in cython:

```
cpdef enum my_enum_type:
    val1 = 0
    ...
```

This only gets a very short mention in [the docs](https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/userguide/language_basics.html?highlight=%22cpdef%20enum%22#c-variable-and-type-definitions) (search for `cpdef enum`)